# How to convert Quantized TFlite Model to Float model?

Tags: tensorflow-lite, quantization

Am trying to run inference by converting quantized fixed point weights to floating point weights but am not able to get bit exact/Nearly match to quantized output. Is there any specific pre/post-processing apart from converting fixed-point weights to floating point weights?